# How to change the parameters of getElementById in a loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am working on a form, and I would like to reset the lines individually without using reset.
How to vary the values ​​of the attribute passed as parameter of the method getElementById in JavaScript using a loop?
 Here is an example of my source code below:

```
<script>
         var element = document.getElementById('#re');
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("#id1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("#id2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("#id3").value = "";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: for(var i=1; i < 4; i++){document.getElementById("id" + i).value = "";}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your IDs have the format shown in your example:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById("id" + i).value = "";
}
```

---

If that's not the case but you know the ID of every element you can put all IDs in an array and use that:

```
var elementIds = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
elementIds.forEach(function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).value = "";
});
```

---

Another solution is to give all the elements you want to reset a specific class and target that:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("resetable-element");
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
  element.value = "";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ids, you can loop through your inputs for example:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example, you could loop through the values 1 - 3 (I assume the `#` in the ID is a typo?):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   document.getElementById('id' + i).value = '';
}
```

If you can identify the elements by something else, such as a class name, you might prefer to iterate over that:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
   element.value = '';
});
```